# Ethereum truffle MetaCoin fails with 'intrinsic gas too low'

Tags: ethereum, truffle

Pretty much as stated in the title, after running truffle test I get this:

```
 TestMetacoin
    1) "before all" hook: prepare suite

  Contract: MetaCoin
    ✓ should put 10000 MetaCoin in the first account
    2) should call a function that depends on a linked library
    > No events were emitted
    ✓ should send coin correctly (6078ms)


  2 passing (6s)
  2 failing

  1) TestMetacoin "before all" hook: prepare suite:
     Error: Intrinsic gas too low
      at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-contract/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
      at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-contract/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:36
      at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:119:13)
      at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
      at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
      at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:12)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:24)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
      at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)

  2) Contract: MetaCoin should call a function that depends on a linked library:
     AssertionError: Library function returned unexpected function, linkage may be broken: expected 0 to equal 20000
      at test/metacoin.js:25:14
      at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
```

My genesis block is as follows:

```
{
    "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
    "difficulty": "0x4000",
    "alloc": {
            "0xfd0ceb7965a0e4c3146c1f901fbab9668653af6b": {
            "balance": "325406000000000"
        }
    },
    "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "coinbase": "0xfd0ceb7965a0e4c3146c1f901fbab9668653af6b",
    "etherbase" : "0xfd0ceb7965a0e4c3146c1f901fbab9668653af6b",
    "timestamp": "0x00",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "extraData": "0x",
    "gasLimit": "0x3d0900"
}
```

And my truffle.js is like this:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      gas: 1000000
    }
  }
};
```

I fail to understand what is wrong with gas at these settings. Even if noone has the exact answer, some additional explanation of the gas limits (not the gas itself) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing genesis block gasLimit to

```
"gasLimit": "0x2FEFD800",
```

config for homestead block to 10 (apparently otherwise there are issues when working with geth):

```
"config": {
            "homesteadBlock": 10
    },
```

and truffle.js gas setting to 5000000.

Tests pass.